# (UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices) calls instead of (Hardware initiated)

Tags: windows, driver, smartcard-reader

I have a Virtual Smart Card Reader driver. It installs correctly at my PC (Windows 7 x64). But installation fails when I install it at another Windows 7 x64 PC. Of course I install them in the same way:

```
devcon install <inf> <hwid>
```

I compared **setupapi.dev.log** files and found the difference at very first line:

- Successful sessions at my PC always starts from

  [Device Install (**Hardware initiated**) - {892EDE5E-BE49-443c-A0B3-005D74F2D69C}\ScFilter\1&3908c5bd&9&01]
- Failed sessions at another PC always starts from

  [Device Install (**UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices**) - root\BixVirtualReader]

I had another Virtual Smart Card Reader at Divice Manager. But I switched it off before the installation of new driver.

Comment: I have the same issue on my own PC at work where another BixVirtualReader was installed. I think you should reboot before re-installing the driver. I haven't had the time to find out what is happening, maybe in some lost hour at work...